# wcf no deserialize the response

Tags: c#, .net-core, soap, wsdl

I've done a lot of research but I can't find the solution to this. I am consuming a soap service and it successfully returns the response in postman and in visual studio with Fiddler also the response is successful. My problem is that this service was working fine in the old 2.0 framework (web reference), now when calling it from Core I get null as response. Do I need to do any extra configuration? where is there information about this?

This is the wsdl: https://maullin.sii.cl/DTEWS/CrSeed.jws?WSDL

This is the xml response:

[image: xml response]

My app:

```
CrSeedClient cliente = new();
getSeedRequest req = new();
string? token = cliente.getSeed(req).getSeedReturn; // return always nulll
```

Reference file:

```
public Seed.getSeedResponse getSeed(Seed.getSeedRequest request)
    {
        return base.Channel.getSeed(request); // return always nulll
    }


 [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="", ReplyAction="*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, SupportFaults=true, Use=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
    Semilla.getSeedResponse getSeed(Semilla.getSeedRequest request);
```

Comment: I don't think it's the optimal solution but it worked for me commenting these attributes: XmlSerializerFormatAttribute. fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs only with .NET Core and the WCF service generator. The code generated from SII WSDL is not compatible with requests sent to the SII web service. Apparently, this needs to be fixed by SII itself.

Comment: I added a comment with the solution.

Comment: I commented the attribute as you indicated, but I get a compiling error

Comment: i am using .net 6 framework with no problem. What is your mistake? Don't do it with creating contract messages.

Comment: I am also using .NET 6, but I have a compile error in the reference.cs file. Is it possible for you to share the code from your reference file?